# Unable to return the text value of a href

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to return the text value of a href, where text is "My account"

I need to check the string to prove I have logged into a website or not.

But I cannot seem to find the correct method. See HTML line and a couple of examples of what I have tried.

```
<a href="/home/manage_account" class="user-info">My account</a>

WebElement linktext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My account"));
System.out.println("link text : "+ linktext);

String linktext1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.user-info")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println("link text : "+ linktext1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `href` of the link, you need to use `.getAttribute("href")`.

```
WebElement linktext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My account"));
System.out.println("link text : "+ linktext.getAttribute("href"));
```

If you want to get text of the link, you need `.getText()`.

```
WebElement linktext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My account"));
System.out.println("link text : "+ linktext.getText());
```

Comment: Tried both of the examples and they are returning
 "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"My account"}"  
 ???

Comment: This works great, thank you.

I had to put a wait clause on the page to give it time to appear.

Answer (score 0):

We can use getText() method to print the innerhtml.

```
String linktext1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.user-info")).getText;
```

Hope this help. thanks.

Comment: Tried :  
  String linktext2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.user-info")).getText();
    System.out.println("link text1 : "+ linktext2);      
It returns no value.

Comment: How about this...,String linktext2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.user-info")).getAttribute("textContent");

Comment: It returns no value ?

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'My account')]")).getText());
```